# Where is the environment file which contain access to "process.env" variable inside of node server on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, reactjs, nginx

My app is running on Reactjs as standalone front-end.
So i deployed my app following this

https://medium.com/@cameronbwhite90/deploy-react-webpack-to-digital-ocean-with-nginx-and-github-b83d1cf4be0b#.fcwshwi7z

Everything worked smoothly except that i could not find Environment file that will give me the access to `process.env` variable on the `production` server.

So this one `process.env.NODE_ENV` is work well in my app.
But i cannot figure out how can i create new env variable like this `process.env.SECRET_TOKEN` inside my app.

I tried `~/.pam_environment` but seems like it didn't work out.
So any one know any solutions for this?

Thanks.

Edited add the purpose off `process.env.SECRET_TOKEN`

I just need to use it to verified the right of the user with my the `SECRET_TOKEN` in my api server.

Comment: Depending on how important it is that your secret token actually remains secret, it may not be the best idea to define it in an environment variable. Perhaps you could edit your question to provide a bit more detail about what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @Nico already added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) project.

What you will need to do is add a `.env` file in the root dir of your project with contents like this:

```
SECRET_TOKEN="very secret token"
```

Then all you need to do in your code is:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

And you are done. `process.env.SECRET_TOKEN` will be defined. Make sure you add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file (if using git) so you don't end up comitting sensitive information.

Comment: It is the good idea to create `.env` file on the production server ,right? i just little bit worry about it.

Comment: Yes, you need to ssh into the server and create that `.env` file manually. Later on you can make that a part of your CI/CD system.

You also need to make sure that your dot files are not gettable through a url. Make sure the .env file is not in your static files directory. Also if you are using nginx as a reverse proxy, look into [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9952850).